# Wrong product thumbnail size

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, thumbnails

I have set the Thumbanil size to 112px, but the page is rendering the original size instead

[image: 1]

That is why the thumbanil is so pixelated

The thumbnails show just fine in Firefox:

[image: 2]

What could be wrong? maybe the Media Image settings are in conflict with the Product Image settings?

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to upload a new image and when uploading image checked what size it getting into image size in media?

You can also try custom thumbnail size:

```
add_image_size('products_image', 112, 112, true);
```

and enque it into loop.

Comment: It creates the sizes specified in the Product Image settings (248x300, 510x600, 112x112px, and the original size ofc) but rather always displays the original size (or medium size, depends on the image); Where can I add the `add_image_size('products_image', 430, 305, true); `?

Comment: sorry for mistake I updated my answer

Comment: `add_image_size('products_image', 112, 112, true);` this sounds like good solution, in which file do I need to add this line?

Comment: add it to function.php   after "add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );"  and then query it where you want with this :  <?php  $idd = get_the_ID();
 $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($idd);  
 $slider_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'products_image');   echo  $slider_image; ?>